# Property 'elements' does not exist on type 'typeof Chart'

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var tooltipCanvas = document.getElementById("tooltip-canvas");

var gradientBlue = canvas.getContext('2d').createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 150);
gradientBlue.addColorStop(0, '#5555FF');
gradientBlue.addColorStop(1, '#9787FF');

var gradientRed = canvas.getContext('2d').createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 150);
gradientRed.addColorStop(0, '#FF55B8');
gradientRed.addColorStop(1, '#FF8787');

var gradientGrey = canvas.getContext('2d').createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 150);
gradientGrey.addColorStop(0, '#888888');
gradientGrey.addColorStop(1, '#AAAAAA');

window.arcSpacing = 0.15;
window.segmentHovered = false;

function textInCenter(value, label) {
  var ctx = tooltipCanvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, tooltipCanvas.width, tooltipCanvas.height)

  ctx.restore();

  // Draw value
  ctx.fillStyle = '#333333';
  ctx.font = '24px sans-serif';
  ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';

  // Define text position
  var textPosition = {
    x: Math.round((tooltipCanvas.width - ctx.measureText(value).width) / 2),
    y: tooltipCanvas.height / 2,
  };

  ctx.fillText(value, textPosition.x, textPosition.y);

  // Draw label
  ctx.fillStyle = '#AAAAAA';
  ctx.font = '8px sans-serif';

  // Define text position
  var labelTextPosition = {
    x: Math.round((tooltipCanvas.width - ctx.measureText(label).width) / 2),
    y: tooltipCanvas.height / 2,
  };

  ctx.fillText(label, labelTextPosition.x, labelTextPosition.y - 20);
  ctx.save();
}

Chart.elements.Arc.prototype.draw = function() {
  var ctx = this._chart.ctx;
  var vm = this._view;
  var sA = vm.startAngle;
  var eA = vm.endAngle;

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(vm.x, vm.y, vm.outerRadius, sA + window.arcSpacing, eA - window.arcSpacing);
  ctx.strokeStyle = vm.backgroundColor;
  ctx.lineWidth = vm.borderWidth;
  ctx.lineCap = 'round';
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
};

var config = {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: ['Pink', 'Grey', 'Blue'],
    datasets: [{
      data: [400, 540, 290],
      backgroundColor: [
        gradientRed,
        gradientGrey,
        gradientBlue,
      ],
    }]
  },
  options: {
    cutoutPercentage: 80,
    elements: {
      arc: {
        borderWidth: 12,
      },
    },
    legend: {
      display: false,
    },
    animation: {
      onComplete: function(animation) {
        if (!window.segmentHovered) {
          var value = this.config.data.datasets[0].data.reduce(function(a, b) {
            return a + b;
          }, 0);
          var label = 'T O T A L';

          textInCenter(value, label);
        }
      },
    },
    tooltips: {
      enabled: false,
      custom: function(tooltip) {
        if (tooltip.body) {
          var line = tooltip.body[0].lines[0],
            parts = line.split(': ');
          textInCenter(parts[1], parts[0].split('').join(' ').toUpperCase());
          window.segmentHovered = true;
        } else {
          window.segmentHovered = false;
        }
      },
    },
  },
};

window.chart = new Chart(canvas, config);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #f3f5f7;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
}

.card {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  max-width: 300px;
  height: 375px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card .about {
  height: 150px;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.card .about h3,
.card .about .lead {
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 0;
}

.card .about h3 {
  font-size: 24px;
}

.card .about .lead {
  color: #aaa;
}

#tooltip-canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 75px;
}

.btn-reload {
  position: absolute;
  top: 280px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  margin-left: -15px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.6;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.btn-reload:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>

<canvas id="canvas" height="200"></canvas>

<!-- Custom tooltip canvas -->
<canvas id="tooltip-canvas" width="150" height="100"></canvas>
```

Hi So im working with chart.js and i have ran into to this issue which i am not able to solve

[image]

```
   "chart.js": "^3.7.1",
 "typescript": "~4.3.5"
```

and my angular version is 12.2.2,what could be a possible solution for this any idea ,there is a github thread as well which is not resolved
[Github Link](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/30544)
Any guidance will be very helpful thank you,i have added a code snippet and a im a beginner to chart ,so any guidance will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

For typescript you can get the arc element from the registry like so:

```js
const arcElement = Chart.registry.elements.get('arc');
```

Comment: Hi @LeeLenalee thank you for the response any idea  how to use ```const arcElement = Chart.registry.elements.get('arc')!; arcElement.prototype.draw``` get the following error ```Property 'prototype' does not exist on type 'Element<AnyObject, AnyObject>```